# vs always crashes with error: reason: 'crashed', code: '5' when trying to attach to running dev container with vs code on Mac

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

My husband has made dev containers for my Magento shop. I am in the pre-tea phase and although everything works on his Microsoft computer and had worked in the morning, before I had updated my MacBook Air to Sonora now VSCode always crashes when I want to connect it to the running dev container. It doesn`t make any difference whether I first open docker or VSCode or if I keep them running in the background. At first, it worked only once but now it doesn't even work once but always crashes.

I have already eliminated all of the unnecessary extensions. There are only microsoft extensions running:

- Dev Containers
- Docker
- Remote-SSH
- Remote-SSH : Editing Configuration Files
- Remote - Tunnels
- Remote Development
- Remote Explorer
- WSL

I am working on the default profile

Each time I press the keys

<kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd> to attach to running container it shows:

> configuring dev container (show log)

the circle with two arrows turns round and round. I cannot press any key or work on the terminal.

[image: This is what I can see while the program is working]

After some time it says:

> The window is not responing
> You can reopen or close the window or keep waiting.

Then I can choose between reopen
<kbd>Close</kbd>
<kbd>Keeep waiting</kbd>
I can also hook don't restore editors

I have no idea what to do. Would be very grateful for help

Comment: Are you sure, you use WSL on Mac? oO

Comment: Not sure, but it might be good to ask this question [in their GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)